# Downcast element when reading from Dictionary in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift, downcast

I'm trying to access an element a dictionary element and downcast it to a type other than AnyObject but keep getting the same compiler error: `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments`.

I know I can just do this using two if statements like so:

```
if let x = dict["key"] {
    if let y = x as? String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I feel there has to be a more elegant solution than this. The format that makes the most sense to me is:

```
if let x = dict["key"] as? String {
    // ...
}
```

But this just results in the error, mentioned above. I've tried dozens of variations of this, but none of it seems to make any difference. Is this something that just can't be done in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried casting the dictionary before you dereference it?  Not sure if it will work if the dictionary isn't homogenous, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I have, the error I get then says `'String' is not identical to AnyObject`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your desired formulation isn't working is that you're trying to unwrap two Optionals with a single `as?`. There are two Optionals because both the subscripting of your dictionary and the attempted cast to `String` return optional values. There isn't a way to do it in one `if` statement that will be runtime-safe, but there is a way:

```
if let x = dict["key"]! as? String {
    println(x)
}
```

The problem is that if `dict["key"]` ends up being `nil`, the forced unwrapping will crash your app. Better to do it this way (you can skip the first `if`), even if it is an extra step:

```
let x: AnyObject? = dict["key"]
if let y = x as? String {
    println(y)
}
```

The extra step is just the cost of working with a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` - if you can get your dictionary type more specific, you won't have to do it any more.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Didn't occur to me that I'd be creating two optionals

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this thing but then i fount out that optional chaining is the solution. Just use

```
if let x = dict["key"]? as? String {
      println(x)
```

}

It gives you both the safety and compactness.

Comment: This does not work for me although it seems as a logical solution

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to use this one-line solution:

```
    if let name = jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as? String {
        println("name is \(name)")
    } else {
        println("property was nil")
    }
```